# How to set Inner Html in a Table Form Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a `table` that contains a `form` where **you can add and delete a form row using javascript** and **save the form row / rows using laravel framework**.

The form row adds and deletes data from the table row but the issue is that the form added on the new table rows or rows cannot submit, the `required` validation method I put doesn't work on the added table row and I actually don't know why. Here is my block of code in my `blade.php`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-danger">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="myTable">
                    <tr>
                    <form action="" method="">
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required></td>
                        <td><input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Current Residence" required></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete</button></td>
                    </form>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                

            </table>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right !important;">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-right: 20px;">Save All</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myCreateFunction()">Add</button>
        </div>

    </div>
  
    <script>
    function myCreateFunction() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(0);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      cell1.innerHTML += '<form action="" method=""><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name">';
      cell2.innerHTML += '<input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">';
      cell3.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Current Residence">';
      cell4.innerHTML += '<button class = "btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button> </form> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete</button>';
    }
    
    function myDeleteFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
    }
    </script>
```

Please guys I really need your help I'll really be grateful if I get quick responses. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.positronx.io/laravel-dynamically-add-or-remove-multiple-input-fields-with-jquery/

Comment: According to MDN: Permitted content in a <tr>: Zero or more <td> and/or <th> elements; script-supporting elements (<script> and <template>) are also allowed.  Your `<form>` element may not be valid markup when inside a `<tr>`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary)

Comment: A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr. Attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the form to it appears after the table (while leaving its contents — table rows, table cells, inputs, etc — behind).